# Union analyzer for Solr

Tags: regex, search, solr, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm playing around with Apache Solr and I would like to use two different analyzers for the same field. Essentially what I want to achieve is to detect certain regular expressions inside the text and treat them as single tokens. The rest of the text should be treated using another kind of analyzer.

This way when a user searches for something matching a regex, she would get a match only if it is exact. On the other hand, the rest of the text would be analyzed using more standard techniques.

Example:

> Some words with a SN-231/II 28-ba some complicated signature field inside that matches a regex.

When a user searches for `SN-231/II 28-ba`, she would get:

> Some words with a **SN-231/II 28-ba** some complicated signature field inside that matches a regex.

When she searches for its components such as `II 28`, she doesn't get a match (correctly). When she searches for other words e.g. `some field`, she would get:

> **Some** words with a SN-231/II 28-ba **some** complicated signature **field** inside that matches a regex.

I was considering using the same text in multiple fields however I'm concerned about text highlighting. It also feels hacky in general. Also I would get a penalty on searches containing both signatures and regular text.